# Regex for cleaning a list of prohibited words from a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm following the accepted answer in this link:
[Replace all words from word list with another string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658187/replace-all-words-from-word-list-with-another-string-in-python)

Despite following the code exactly as describe in the above solution, I can't seem to remove the characters from my string. I am not receiving any errors in the console. Could anybody point out what I am doing wrong? Here is a reproducible example. Thank you.

```
example = "(-) This is an example of a string € which is + not being cleaned // correctly"
prohibited_strings = ["(-)","€","+","//"]
regex_cleaner = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % r'\b|\b'.join(map(re.escape, prohibited_strings)))
example = regex_cleaner.sub("", example)
```

Comment: `\b` meaning is context dependent, none of your strings are "words", they neither start nor end with word chars, thus why did you bother adding word boundaries to the pattern?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi Wiktor, this is a small section of my overall code. My real code includes hundreds of alphabetical words also. And my example string is thousands of words long. this is why I added the boundary. The solution above also uses `\b`.

Comment: Ok, I see. You cannot use `\b` in this case. See the [linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970), try unambiguous word boundaries. You might need a custom solution if those listed in that answer do not work fine for you.

Comment: I do not understand. How do I remove a list with a mix of 'words' and 'non words' such as `prohibited_strings = ["(-)","€","+","//", "fhd", thoias","opk"]`  ? The link you gave does not answer my question unfortunately. I am working in Python and don't understand the content in that link. @WiktorStribiżew edit: I will try the link you gave above. Thank you.

Comment: Try `r'(?<!\w)(?:{})(?!\w)'.format( "|".join(map(re.escape,prohibited_strings)) )`, see solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996079/match-a-whole-word-in-a-string-using-dynamic-regex).

Comment: Fantastic. Your suggestion worked. I will use that code for non-words, and my original attempt for 'words'. @WiktorStribiżew